# OK to use Windows while a RAID array is building?

Tags: windows-7, raid, sata, software-raid

I've just put together a nice clean, fresh install of Windows 7 x64, and my two primary harddisks are building a software RAID1 array in the background while I type this.

[image]

But I want to move over about 90GB of files onto these harddrives, and install a bunch of applications, and Service Pack 1. I know my computer is running more slowly while the RAID array builds, but is there any danger if I do these tasks before it's complete?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what (hardware) RAID is designed for! No danger apart from the speed issues.

... I would just lay off excessive hard drive tasks such as defrag/scanning etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response! (I assume the fact that I'm using software RAID doesn't come into it?)

Comment: @Johnny W - No real difference apart from it will be even slower!